# Linked List in C (apparently malloc doesn't want to be my friend)

Tags: c, linked-list

I was so pleased with myself getting this to work last night without any errors or warnings on my first try too! But, of course, I changed a bunch of stuffed and screwed it up...
When I tried to gdb it, the list from this.ytxt seemed load to memory just fine. I think the problem was writing it. Now. it works again but only writes the first line of the file. I commented out whole functions and printf'd test marks and still couldn't figure it out.
the idea is to read a variable number of lines from a file and print them in pairs. (Actually
it was meant to be like study flashcards but I never got around to that part)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct member{      //This emulates a dictionary
    char key[20];   //and links each word+definition pair to the next pair.
    char def[20];
    struct member *ptr;
};
struct member *root;
struct member *curr;
FILE *f;

int fill_list(){                //Fill each member struct with next two lines of
    curr=root;
    char this[20];              //FILE *f
    while(EOF){
        if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
        strcpy(curr->key,this);
        if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
        strcpy(curr->def,this);
        curr=curr->ptr;
        curr=malloc(sizeof(struct member));
        curr->ptr=0;
    }
    return 0;
}

void free_all(){
    curr=NULL;
    while(curr!=root){
        curr=root;
        while(curr->ptr)curr=curr->ptr;
        free(curr);
    }
}

 int terminate(int i){  //The terminate function closes file and
    free_all(); //frees malloc'd memory, then returns main func's
    fclose(f);  //return value.
    return i;
}

int main(){
    f=fopen("this.txt","r");
    if(!f)return -1;
    root=malloc(sizeof(struct member));
    root->ptr=NULL;
    fill_list();
    curr=root;
    if ( curr != 0 ) {
      while ( curr != 0 ) {
        printf( "%s", curr->key );
        curr = curr->ptr;
      }
    }
    free_all();
    return terminate(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on Chad's answer, you could have:

```
int fill_list(){                //Fill each member struct with next two lines of
    struct member *new_mem;
    curr=root;
    char this[20];              //FILE *f
    while(1){ /* relying on the breaks below to exit the loop */
        if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
        strcpy(curr->key,this);
        if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
        strcpy(curr->def,this);
        /* create the new member */
        new_mem=malloc(sizeof(struct member));
        /* set the new member's next ptr to NULL */
        new_mem->ptr = NULL;
        /* set the current member's next to the new member */
        curr->ptr=new_mem;
        /* current is now the new member */
        curr = new_mem;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: thought I'd just add that if I was going to make slight modifications to your code this is what I'd do. If I were to do it from scratch I wouldn't structure the loop that way or have unnecessary global variables like *curr*. Same goes for the point made by sarnold where you only have a single temporary buffer. Not to mention that your last entry in the list could be invalid; it might be a better idea to allocate the next member entry in the list *only after* you successfully read the two strings into two temporary buffers.

Comment: that got a couple of lines back, still have seg fault but im closer, and now i know the kind of thing to look for. well, more than before

Comment: Really? With this fix and selbie's it runs ok for me. EDIT: just realised you tried selbie's code 4 mins ago.

Comment: yours got it to save the file lines correctly and his made it get rid of the segfault and accually run. thanks so much i would vote up, but i don't even have enough rep-points to do that for you. thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

Some possible bugs:

Do not have variables named "this".  "this" is C++ reserved word.  (Probably ok if you are compiling as C)

Your free_all() function looks suspicious.  It took me a few glances to figure out what was going on.  It looks like you are trying to free the linked list by traversing to the tail, deallocating the last node, and starting back from the top of the root again.    This will have n-squared performance compared to freeing in a linear fashion.  I think you want to say this:

```
void free_all()
{
    struct member* curr = root;
    while (curr)
    {
        struct member* next = curr->ptr;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank ya much. that makes sense! it's certainly simpler than the web i wove too.

Comment: WOW! YOUR MY HERO! that did it!

Answer (score 3):

```
int fill_list(){                //Fill each member struct with next two lines of
    curr=root;
    char this[20];              //FILE *f
    while(EOF){
        /* ... */
```

Your `while(EOF)` loop will never terminate here -- `EOF` is defined in `stdio.h` to `(-1)`:

```
/* End of file character.
   Some things throughout the library rely on this being -1.  */
#ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif
```

It would be unwise to redefine `EOF` in your own program.

If you really want an infinite loop, *please* use one of `while(1)` or `for(;;)`; Both of these are very obviously infinite loops, and both of these are common C idioms for infinite loops. Better would be re-writing your loop's exit condition into the `while()`, but sometimes that is difficult. (`do { /* foo */ } while ()` is sometimes the perfect solution, and is probably better here.)

I'm not sure what exactly you should do to fix your `while()` loop condition, because I'm not entirely sure what it is supposed to be doing:

```
while(EOF){
    if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
    strcpy(curr->key,this);
    if(!fgets(this,20,f)) break;
    strcpy(curr->def,this);
```

You might as well be reading directly into `curr->key` and `curr->def`. (Reading into temporary storage makes sense if you want to keep your objects consistent even in the face of errors, but you'd need *two* temporary variables for that, and update the values after *both* IO commands. Up to you.)

```
    curr=curr->ptr;
    curr=malloc(sizeof(struct member));
    curr->ptr=0;
}
```

In this small piece, you over-write the `curr` pointer with the value of the next node. Then you allocate a new node and over-write the `curr` pointer again. Then you null out the `curr->ptr` pointer in the newly allocated object. The `curr` object now has uninitialized `curr->key` and `curr->def` character arrays. Is this intentional? (Allowing half-initialized objects to live in your program is usually a recipe for disaster.)

Comment: yeah, the loops exits with the breaks, the EOF wasn't meant to be important, i just got tired of while(1) and decided to mix things up a bit, i suppose there are probably a dozen or so exceptional circumstances that could kill my computers ram if i don't close the loop properly, but hey, sometimes im satisfied with "good enough". as for the writing over curr, thank you, i addressed that just a minute or so ago and it fixed the fill0 func

Comment: btw, im not sure if i should be impressed or terrified by your reputation points. very impressive

Comment: Thanks Timmmay :) But [there are some very impressive reputations around here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), I'm just a persistent sort of guy. :)

Answer (score 2):

In `fill_list()` you incorrectly allocating objects.

```
curr=root;

// now curr is a copy of root->ptr
curr=curr->ptr;

// curr allocated properly, but not attached to root at all!
curr = malloc(...)
```

Comment: thanks, should I *curr=malloc(...) instead? if i seem thick, i've never tried linking malloc'd stuff before